# MySQL/Drupal: conditions in JOIN ON statement

Tags: mysql, drupal

I manage to hang my db server doing a query:

```
SELECT d.name, COUNT(DISTINCT stats_log.id ) AS hits, COUNT( DISTINCT stats_log.ip ) AS views
FROM stats_log
LEFT JOIN node ON node.nid = stats_log.nid
LEFT JOIN  taxonomy_term_data d ON d.tid IN (node.category_tid, node.category_tid2)
GROUP BY d.tid
ORDER BY hits
```

But this works fine:

```
SELECT d.name, COUNT(DISTINCT stats_log.id ) AS hits, COUNT( DISTINCT stats_log.ip ) AS views
FROM stats_log
LEFT JOIN node ON node.nid = stats_log.nid
LEFT JOIN  taxonomy_term_data d ON node.category_tid = d.tid
GROUP BY d.tid
ORDER BY hits
```

so my question is... am I just not noticing some mistake in my query or ON has some restrictions or interesting behavior that I dont know about?

- `node.category_tid2` values are mostly NULL
- `d.tid` is a primary key

Answer (score 0):

There is an SQL issue here

LEFT JOIN  taxonomy_term_data d ON d.tid IN (node.category_tid, node.category_tid2)

should be:

LEFT JOIN  taxonomy_term_data d ON (d.tid = node.category_tid OR d.tid = node.category_tid2)

Comment: and whats the difference? same result using both